# Pattern Matching for java using regex

Tags: java, regex

I have a Long string that I have to parse for different keywords. For example, I have the String:

```
"==References== This is a reference ==Further reading== *{{cite book|editor1-last=Lukes|editor1-first=Steven|editor2-last=Carrithers|}} * ==External links=="
```

And my keywords are

```
'==References==' '==External links==' '==Further reading=='
```

I have tried  a lot of combination of regex but i am not able to recover all the strings.

the code i have tried:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\=+[A-Za-z]\\=+");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(textBuffer.toString());

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
}
```

Comment: `==External links==` and `==Further reading==` have space characters in them which will not be matched by `[A-Za-z]`. An improvement would be to change `[A-Za-z]` to `[A-Za-z ]` but I suspect there are still additional issues with your regex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to escape the `=` sign. And you should also include a whitespace inside your character class.

Apart from that, you also need a quantifier on your character class to match multiple occurrences. Try with this regex:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("=+[A-Za-z ]+=+");
```

You can also increase the flexibility to accept any characters in between two `==`'s, by using `.+?` (You need reluctant quantifier with `.` to stop it from matching everything till the last `==`) or `[^=]+`:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("=+[^=]+=+");
```

---

If the number of `=`'s are same on both sides, then you need to modify your regex to use capture group, and backreference:

```
"(=+)[^=]+\\1"
```

Comment: I had used the whitespace, but i wasnt using the quantifier. Worked perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: `=+` can cause mismatch. This regex will match `=Lukes|editor1-first=` and `=Carrithers|}} * ==`. `Pattern.compile("==[^=]+==");` seems to be better here.

Comment: @Pshemo : I might need to match string like ===Example=== or =Example=. The number of "='s" is not fixed. i am sorry i didn't these them in the examples.

Comment: @Nikhil. Would you like to match - `==Example=`?